# Ability to control individual XYZs of mapping node

Tags: node-editor, add-on, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

So, I know about the Separate/Combine XYZ nodes, but they're a little cumbersome & annoying. Is there an addon or something I could get to have my node look something like this? (mockup)
[image]

I just want the ability to influence specific axes directly. let me know if there's some other alternative as well!

Comment: Build a node group that looks like that.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, I don't think that it's logical to have both the vector input and the components exposed at the same time. It just wouldn't make sense and I don't think you could do that even if you make a custom node group as stated by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos
Either you chose the vector only or components only, you can't have both.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka True, there may be some potential undefined behavior. One would have to define how they are combined, but from the user standpoint it may always seem arbitrary

Answer (score 2):

You can not. Mapping does exactly what it is designed to do - work with vectors. Adding float sockets to it will be nothing more than a crooked crutch. You need more good organization of your node trees than a node like this.

So the best thing you can do is create a group that will do exactly what is expected inside:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One might want to convert rotation values to radians since user is likely to enter degrees. Math node has a function for that.

Comment: I have a question : In the second node group, how did you add those black dots that act like separators?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka You can add empty inputs in the node group.

Comment: Yes, but how? When I add a new Input, it always default to a float grey input and I can only change it to the Vector, Color or Shader type, I don't know how he did this.